# What data structure should be used while designing algo for multiplication and division problems?

Tags: math, python-2.7, data-structures, division, multiplication

Considering basic example of multiplication where 12*24 = 288. Now I am looking for single or multiple data structures where I can keep each an every information of the intermediate steps performed during multiplication. e.g. 2*4 fetches 8, 1*4 fetches 4, etc.
I need to store such intermediate information so as to facilitate me to tell user exactly where he went wrong in his operations.

http://tutrr.com

Answer (score 0):

Focus on first on the capability you need to provide.

For example, the user will enter one digit of his answer, you need to check it and give feedback. For example in 28 x 57 assuming you are teaching traditional "long multiplication" then the user needs to mulitply 28 by 7, recording 6 in the units, carrying 5 and then 9, remembering to adding the carried 5 and then 1. suppose he enters 4 in the tens column, you might want to say "Yes, 7 x 2 is 14, but don't forget to add the 5 you carried"

So to support this you need functions such as

```
  getCorrectWorkingDigit( int leftDigitIndex, int rightDigitIndex)
```

In this case we'd call

```
  getCorrectWorrkingDigit( 1, 0 ) and get 9 as the answer
```

and

```
  getWorkingCarryDigit( int leftDigitIndex, int rightDigitIndex)
```

so

```
  getWorkingCarryDigit( 1, 0 ) and get 5 as the answer
```

You will need a few other such functions, including functions for the final answer's digits.

Now, what data structure would allow you to do this? Your requirement is to enable your functions to be implemented. Well clearly you could build some kind of array of objects, representing each Working position, and each position in the final answer. But I think that's overkill, you can implement those functions directly against the question. All you actually need are the two integers (28 and 57 in my example) you can compute the function values on the fly, no need for keeping the target.

Having written all that I've just realised that you probably also want to keep the values the user entered, and for that a data structure might be useful, keeping the individual digits will be convenient.

For and "row" of working, and for the final result, how about an array of digits, where the index corresponds to the power of 10, so represent 196 as

```
 [6, 9, 1]
```

and for the working put that in a Set, keyed by the power of ten of the right digit. In my 28 x 57:

```
 0 -> [6, 9, 1]   // this is 7 x 28
10 -> [0, 4, 1]   // this is 5 x 28
```